# equal height column if using chunk filter in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css

```js
angular.module('app', ['angular.filter']).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myJson = [{name:"mayank1","desc":"Lorem"}, {name:"mayank2","desc":"Lorem fkjkerjt lkjlkjerlkt kljeltkjerlkt lkjerlktj"},{name:"mayank3","desc":"abc def something more"},{name:"mayank4","desc":"orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."}];
})
```

```css
.item{
  background:#ddd; 
  border:1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-filter@0.5.7" data-semver="0.5.7" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="json in myJson|chunkBy:4" class="row">
    <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="item in json">
      <strong>{{item.name}}</strong><br>
      {{item.desc}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use a filter chunkBy so I can decide how many item to display in a row, but now I'm having trouble making them equal height. ouch.